# Why is my foundation email width expanding to 100%?

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation, html-email, inky

My email is basically two images side-by-side with a cta button underneath. On mobile the email is fine. On desktop the second set of images and button width expands to 100%.  The inky code looks fine to me. Am I placing the button in the wrong location. PLEASE HELP
Mobile: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fgqa.club/mobile-email.jpg
Desktop: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fgqa.club/desktop-email.jpg

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help but ask, do you need someone to fix the image for you? It would be good to see the HTML to suggest any fixes

Comment: Yep we need the HTML --- probably some wrongly placed or extra/missing `</td></tr></table>`